# Output from printf does not show in cygwin terminal?

Tags: c, terminal, printf

I wrote a very small program called cow.c. When I try to run it from the cygwin terminal after compiling, I get no output. There are no errors on compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%s\n", "COW?");
    return(0);
}
```

EDIT: I have a feeling that the problem is with cygwin...are there any steps I need to take to ensure that output is printed to the cygwin terminal instead of lost in the void?

Comment: try to do like this : `printf("COW?\n");` .. btw this should work

Comment: Edited original post to explain problem better.

Comment: How do you compile and run the program? (i.e.: what commands do you execute in the terminal?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run:

`gcc cow.c -o app`

Then type:

`./app`

This should work.

Comment: `gcc cow.c -o app` creates an executable program under your *current* directory. In order to run it you should type `./app` which runs the program you've just built.